# How to prove, no tame knot is isotopic to a non tame knot?

Tags: geometric-topology

Please let me ask the following question.

I have read in Wikipedia, quote:
A polygonal knot is a knot whose image in R^3 is the union of a finite set of line segments. A tame knot is any knot equivalent to a polygonal knot.

But it is yet unclear that a knot is equivalent to a polygonal knot. Could you give some definition.
And how do you prove that no tame knot is ambient isotopic to a non tame knot, without using the theory of Reidemeister move?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Must $P$ be unchanged after $H$?

Comment: @JoshChen Yes. I really need H does not take P.

Comment: Suppose $L$ is contained in $P$.

Comment: @studiosus, do you mean that H can do it if the condition holds?

Comment: I mean that a line segment contained in P already works. No, can you show that any two line segments are isotopic?

Comment: @studiosus, No I can't. I have read that a knot is said tame if only if it can be represented by a polygon. It probably means a polygon having only finite edges. But it did not state the meaning of that a polygon represents a knot.

Comment: Do you know how to show that each rotation in $R^3$ is isotopic to the identity map? Can you show that same for translations? Dilations?

Comment: @studiosus. Both rotations are ambient isotopies. So they are ambient isotopic to the identity. The same holds for translations and dilations.